# Name mapping does not work when exporting shape file from postgres using phsql2shp command

Tags: linux, postgis

I am exporting a shapefile from a PostgreSQL database using the [phsql2shp](https://postgis.net/windows_downloads/) from PostGIS package on Linux (using WSL on Windows). I am specifying a mappings file with the `-m` parameter. The problem is that the mapping does not seem to work. For example, this is the command I am executing:

```
#dump_data.sh
pgsql2shp -kf shapefile.shp -m mappings.txt -h host_ip \
-u shema_name -P password db_name \
"SELECT * FROM table_name limit 10"
```

and that is the `mapping.txt` file that I am using:

```
#mapping.txt
play PlayDesign \n
play_section AcrIdent \n
```

The resulting Shapefile has the following column names:

[image]

For some reason the first mapping succeeded but not the second one which should be `AcrIdent` **not** "play_secti"

I suspect this has something to do with the EOL (end of line) scheme. I have set my visual studio code set to `CRLF` for the `mapping.txt` file.

**Note**: Ideally I would like to specify a longer than 10 character name for the resulting column but it seems that this is a limitation of ShapeFiles

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, it seems that only the first 10 characters of the postresql fields names are compaired against the first column. "play" does work, because it less than 10 characters; "play_section" is not recognized, because it is compaired against "play_secti".

Oddly even more, the same mapping does work for shp2pgsql.

I think it might be considered a bug. The workaround, anyway, is to write only the first 10 character of the field's name in the first column (if it doesn't collide with another field's name.)

I think, this is the point:

```
diff --git a/loader/pgsql2shp-core.c b/loader/pgsql2shp-core.c
index 1596dc206..06226e951 100644
--- a/loader/pgsql2shp-core.c
+++ b/loader/pgsql2shp-core.c
@@ -1536,7 +1536,7 @@ ShpDumperOpenTable(SHPDUMPERSTATE *state)
         * use this to create the dbf field name from
         * the PostgreSQL column name */
        {
-           const char *mapped = colmap_dbf_by_pg(&state->column_map, dbffieldname);
+           const char *mapped = colmap_dbf_by_pg(&state->column_map, pgfieldname);
            if (mapped)
            {
                strncpy(dbffieldname, mapped, 10);
```

The prototype of colmap_dbf_by_pg is:

```
const char *colmap_dbf_by_pg(colmap *map, const char *pgname);
```

I understand it should be called with the pg field's name, but it is called instead with the dbf field's name.

After applying this change, it behaves as expected.

Comment: I requested an user id to OSGeo, in order to report this bug: To: mantra-request@osgeo.org
From: Giovanni Zezza
Subject: Postgis - suspected bug in pgsql2shp
Message-ID: <65a418a2-f444-621e-786f-f9e12e8d98ea@gmail.com>